# Creating models from $P'=kP^a$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So we were given values of $a=1,2,\frac{1}{5}$ and
$P'=kP^a$. I got $P=Ce^{kt}$ for $a=1$.
How do you put $a=\frac{1}{5}$ with it being a model that makes sense? Are there integral rules I don’t know that keep it from getting overly complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution of the differential equation:

$$u'=Pu^{n+1}+Qu$$ is

$$u=\dfrac{e^{\int Qdx}}{\sqrt[n]{C-n\int P e^{n\int Qdx}dx}}$$ for some constant $C$. This is derived in the following manner:
$$z'+Az=B$$ has the general solution of $$z=e^{-\int A dx}(C+\int Be^{\int A dx}dx)$$ By putting $u^q=z$, we obtain
$$qu^{q-1}u'+Au^q=B$$
$$qu'+Au=Bu^{1-q}$$ or
$$qu' = Bu^{1-q}-Au.$$ Substitute $q=-n$, $A = nQ, B = -nP$
$$-nu' = -nPu^{n+1}-nQu$$
$$\boxed{u'=Pu^{n+1}+Qu}$$ Therefore,
$$u^{-n} = e^{-n\int Qdx}\left[C-n\int Pe^{n\int Qdx}dx\right]$$ or
$$\boxed{\boxed{u=\dfrac{e^{\int Qdx}}{\sqrt[n]{C-n\int P e^{n\int Qdx}dx}}}}$$ assuming $n\neq 0$. Putting $Q=0,$ we obtain
$$u=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{C-n\int P dx}}$$ which, for a constant $P=k$, is
$$u= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{C-nkx}},$$ and taking the limit as $n\to 0$ corresponds to the exponential solution.

Comment: Would this be a solution you learn in calculus 1? I only ask because I looks like something beyond what was taught in class.

Comment: @tom I discovered just recently that this is not original, apparently. It also goes by the name of a Bernoulli Equation.